# Add method to a class

Tags: ruby

I need to add method `color` to a class `Car` to get this:

```
car = Car.new
car.color
# => 'red'
```

This is my code:

```
car.color
# => undefined method `color'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add a method for all cars, do what Marek suggests. Alternatively, you can add `color` only to *this* `car`.

```
car = Car.new
def car.color
  'red'
end

car.color # => "red"

another_car = Car.new
another_car.color  # ~> -:11:in `<main>': undefined method `color' for #<Car:0x00007faba40b9da0> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Wait, really?!? That's bizzare!

Comment: @AJFaraday: just regular ruby :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I love random oddities like this.

Comment: To extend, this is called "singleton method". You can read more about this here: https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/ruby-singleton-methods/.

Comment: And then `car.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new { def color; "I am #{super}"; end })` :)

Comment: Thanks to all! Works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can simply reopen `Car` class:

```
class Car
  def wheel_count
    4
  end
end

car = Car.new
car.wheel_count # => 4
car.color # ~> -:9:in `<main>': undefined method `color' for #<Car:0x00007fc06794c918> (NoMethodError)

class Car
  def color
    'red'
  end
end

car = Car.new
car.wheel_count # => 4
car.color # => "red"
```

Comment: I took the liberty of highlighting the "reopen" aspect of this. :)

Comment: Good point, thanks for this. :)